# Is there a way to launch Safari or some other external browser on URLs in Flutter apps on iOS?

Tags: flutter

I have this code:

```dart
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
...

      await launch("https://example.org/bigprizes");
```

It launches a web view within the app on iOS. Instead, I want it to launch in Safari or some other external browser of the user's choice. Is there a way to do that in Flutter?

Comment: Whoever downvoted, would you care to explain what is missing?

Answer (score 2):

Look at Step 4 in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/flutter-url-launcher

```
await launch("https://example.org/bigprizes", forceSafariVC: false);
```

Answer (score 1):

`url_launcher` plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) has methods `launchUrl()` and `launchUrlString()` which both has a property `mode` where you can specify how the app will open the URL. More details on the [Launch mode documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/url_launcher_string/LaunchMode.html)

Basically you can call it like this:

```
static Future<void> launchURL(String url) async {
  if (await canLaunchUrlString(url)) {
    // Passes the URL to the OS to be handled by another application.
    await launchUrlString(url, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Comment: this no longer seems to work

Answer (score -1):

**check this package** https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_linkify it's may be useful for your project

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I'm not trying to put links into text. I'm trying to change what happens when they are tapped. The package you referenced relies on `url_launcher` which opens the URL within the app on iOS. I want it to open in an external browser.

Comment: https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-open-url-examples can you check this out

Comment: Nirmal, I looked at that link but didn't see an answer to my question.